# Problem with ImageView trembling in View in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view

When I add ImageView using animation it works smoothly fine. But when I set up the player (astronaut) to be moved with interaction, the ImageView keeps trembling when not moving.

---

**Problem**

[image: gif image showing the player trembling]

---

I have attached all the related codes in Kotlin below

---

**MyGameObject** class

```
open class MyGameObject(var x:Int, var y:Int, var dx:Int, var dy:Int, var image:Drawable) {
    var width:Int = 300
    var height:Int = 300

    open fun move(canvas:Canvas)
    {
        x += dx
        y += dy

        if(x > (canvas.width - width) || x < 0)
            dx = -dx
        if(y > (canvas.height - height) || y < 0)
            dy = -dy
        image.setBounds(x, y, x+width, y+width)
        image.draw(canvas)
    }
}
```

**Astronaut** class (player)

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

class Astronaut(x:Int, y:Int, dx:Int, dy:Int, image: Drawable) : MyGameObject(x, y,dx, dy, image) {
    var px:Int=0
    var py:Int=0

    override fun move(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (px > x)
            x += 5
        else
            x -= 5

        if (py > y)
            y += 5
        else
            y -= 5

        image.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height)
        image.draw(canvas)

    }
}
```

**MySurfaceView** class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.*

class MySurfaceView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SurfaceView(context, attrs), Runnable {

    var paint = Paint()
    var isRunning = true
    lateinit var myThread: Thread
    lateinit var myHolder: SurfaceHolder
    var myGameObjects = ArrayList<MyGameObject>()
    val astronautImage = context!!.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.astronaut, null)
    val astronaut = Astronaut(100, 100, 0, 0, astronautImage)

    init {
        val asteroid = context!!.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.asteroid, null)
        myGameObjects.add(MyGameObject(100, 100, 10, 10, asteroid))
        myGameObjects.add(astronaut)
        myThread = Thread(this)
        myThread.start()
        myHolder = holder // controls access to canvas
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        //return super.onTouchEvent(event)
        astronaut.px = event!!.x.toInt()
        astronaut.py = event!!.y.toInt()
        return true
    }

    override fun run() {
        while(isRunning)
        {
            if(!myHolder.surface.isValid)
            {
                continue
            }
            val canvas: Canvas = myHolder.lockCanvas() // prevent other threads using this section
            canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, canvas.width.toFloat(), canvas.height.toFloat(), paint)
            for(gameObject in myGameObjects)
            {
                gameObject.move(canvas)
            }
            myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried to change values in astronaut class and MySurfaceView class but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you haven't set a fallback option in case astronaut is not moving. When `px` is equal to astronaut's `x`, astronaut goes into the else block because the `px > x` is false, then it moves `5 pixels` to the left, then it goes back to initial position because now `px` is greater than `x`.

So, based by your logic, the condition should be:

```
x = x + when {
    px > x -> 5
    px == x -> 0
    px < x -> -5
}
```

same with the `y` coordinate, you need a case when the astronaut is **NOT** moving... That's why the bitmap *trembles* in a diagonal path.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant! this solution helped me realise the logics behind this bug.